# BaPoster: Custom Title Box with Color and Logo

Tags: titles, posters, baposter

I am trying to match my custom TeX based `baposter` which I usually present at conferences, to a specific poster template prescribed by an event.

Specifically, how can I change the `baposter` class so as to get the output attached below?

I would like to make a title box where I can choose the color and set the logo on the right and insert a black line. Everything below the black line is the same as the usual `baposter`.

[image: Custom Title Head with Choice of Background Color and Logo Placement]

Comment: The `baposter` code isn't very modular, and there are no hooks to format the poster title. So without delving into the code a lot, this is not an easy fix at all.